# Why doesn't my logistic regression algorithm work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to compute my gradient for a multiclass classification model with logistic regression and it seems not to be working properly.

This is the data that I am using for this model.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

# Create x and y datasets
path = '/kaggle/input/digit-recognizer'

# Set train and test sets
data = pd.read_csv(path + '/train.csv', nrows=6000)
x_train, y_train = data.iloc[:4800, 1:].values, data.iloc[:4800, 0].values
x_test, y_test = data.iloc[4800:, 1:].values, data.iloc[4800:, 0].values

# Normalize and expand dims
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255, x_test / 255
y_train, y_test = np.expand_dims(y_train, 1), np.expand_dims(y_test, 1)

assert len(x_train) == len(y_train)
assert len(x_test) == len(y_test)

x_train.shape, y_train.shape
((4800, 784), (4800, 1))
```

Here is the following code where I try to implement **gradient descent**:

```
def Sigmoid(z):
    from math import e 
    return 1 / (1 + e**-z)

def CostFunction(h, y, m):
    j = -(1/m) * (y @ np.log(h) + (1-y) @ np.log(1-h))
    return j

def GradientDescent(X, y, theta, n_classes):
    import numpy as np
    
    # Useful variables
    m = len(y)
    
    theta0, theta1 = [x.copy() for x in theta]
    grad0, grad1 = [np.zeros(x.shape) for x in [theta0, theta1]]
    y_vec = np.zeros((m, n_classes))
    j = 0
    
    for i in range(m):
        y_vec[i, y[i]] = 1 
        
        ### Forward propagation
        a0 = np.concatenate(([1], X[i]))
        a1 = np.concatenate(([1], Sigmoid(theta0 @ a0)))
        a2 = Sigmoid(theta1 @ a1)
        
        h = a2
        j += CostFunction(h, y_vec[i], m)
        
        ### Backpropagation
        delta2 = a2 - y_vec[i]
        delta1 = theta1.T @ delta2 * (a1 * (1 - a1))
        
        grad0 += np.expand_dims(delta1[1:], 1) @ np.expand_dims(a0, 0)
        grad1 += np.expand_dims(delta2, 1) @ np.expand_dims(a1, 0)
        
    grad0 = grad0 / m
    grad1 = grad1 / m
    
    return j, [grad0, grad1]
```

Now comes the training process.

```
### Create theta parameters
n_layers = 3
n_classes = 10

# Weigth matrix dims(i, j) = (number of nodes, input shape + bias)
theta0 = np.random.uniform(0, 0.01, (24, x_train.shape[1] + 1))
theta1 = np.random.uniform(0, 0.01, (n_classes, len(theta0) + 1))

theta_params = [theta0, theta1]
```

```
### Train parameters
%%time
epochs = 200
alpha = 0.001

j, t = np.zeros(epochs), theta_params.copy()
for i in range(epochs):  
    print("Iterarion: {}/{}".format(i + 1, epochs))
    j[i], g = GradientDescent(x_train, y_train, t, n_classes)
    print(j[i])
    t[0] = t[0] - a * g[0]
    t[1] = t[1] - a * g[1]
```

The cost starts from `J=7.2583` and goes down to approximately `J=3.5223`, where it gets stuck.

Then, whenever I try to predict any of the samples from the training or test sets it outputs the same approximate probability for all classes.

```
def Predict(X, theta):
    import numpy as np
    
    # Useful variables
    m = len(X)
    
    theta0, theta1 = [x for x in theta]
    h = np.zeros(m)
    
    for i in range(m):        
        ### Forward propagation
        a0 = np.concatenate(([1], X[i]))
        a1 = np.concatenate(([1], Sigmoid(theta0 @ a0)))
        a2 = Sigmoid(theta1 @ a1)
              
        print(a2)
        h[i] = np.argmax(a2)
          
    return h

Predict(x_train[:1], t)
[0.20078521 0.19842413 0.20535222 0.1953332  0.19425315 0.19302124
 0.20107485 0.19589331 0.19688894 0.19526526]
array([2.])
```

Notice that I'm am printing the results of the hypothesis probability for each node in the last layer during the Predict function.

Anyone could point me the direction by sharing some tips?

Comment: Please share your dataset if it is open-source.

Comment: I used the MNIST Digit Recognizer dataset for training, from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer